# Matplotlib 1.4.2 / 1.4.3 don't install from source

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I have Matplotlib 1.3.1 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 system and thought it was time to upgrade to 1.4.2. I never get the latest version for compatibility reasons (some packages that use Matplotlib might stop working). I then downloaded the tarball, uncompressed its contents into a folder and executed "sudo python setup.py build". However, I got the following error (last few lines only):

```
c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/mplutils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxsupport.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxx_extensions.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxextensions.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -lfreetype -lstdc++ -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/ft2font.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a(si_class_type_info.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

I then tried the same with Matplotlib 1.4.3 (why not?) and got the same results.

What's going on here?

Thanks so much for any help.

Fausto

Comment: sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib ? (Let me know if it works)

Comment: No, it didn't, but produced an entirely different error message this time. No problem. I guess this is one of those things that worked beautifully in the past but stopped working all of a sudden -- and I will never know why. I will stick with 1.3.1. Thanks a lot for your help.